# Garbage collected languages for desktop GUI applications

Tags: qt, user-interface, cross-platform, desktop-application, d

I'm still a newbie programmer and I am looking at some garbage collected languages that are suited for writing desktop GUI applications. The language must be available on Windows, OSX and Linux. I say "garbage collected" instead of high level since a language like D isn't quite high level (imo) but is garbage collected, compiles to native code and gives near C++ performance. However the most developed GUI toolkit for D is DWT, wich is a port of SWT. The few SWT apps I have used look ugly on every platform. If D had a Qt binding that would be great, but the only thing I could find was QtD which seems to be a dead project.

Languages I am aware of:
Java
Python
D

I'd rather not use C# with Mono and syntax-wise I prefer languages similar to C/C++.

Are there any others, and what would you suggest?

EDIT: The language doesn't have to compile to native code, compiling to bytecode and running in a VM is just fine.

Comment: It's not compiled, and thus doesn't strictly answer your question, but you might also want to consider the new Qt Quick using Javascript. It uses V8 which has performance on par with a lot of native-compiled languages. Also, Javascript integrates easily with C++, which should allow you to write performance-critical parts in C++ if you need to.

Comment: @NATE C-K
I doesn't have to compile down to native code. I was thinking of looking at QML after Qt5 as it is getting a major update. However QML still doesn't use the native widgets of the platform and probably won't until Qt 5.1 AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

Every programming language that I know, that has a compiler to the native code, uses some C or C++ GUI toolkit for GUI. SWT/DWT uses GTK on Linux/Unix for an example. If SWT applications look ugly to you, then either you did not configure the GTK theme or you did something with the look&feel initialisation. SWT applications look exactly the same as any "native" GUI application.

Even though I am a former C++ programmer, and no matter how I dislike it now, I would still recommend C++ to you because you asked for programming language with compiler that compiles to native binary. Additional requirement you specified is the garbage collector. Use the `libgc` in your C++ applications, and that is all you need. More about it here: http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/libgc.html .

In the field of programming languages with native compilers I am more/less settled with D, but unfortunately, D has no actively-developed GUI ToolKit as we speak. That will be solved soon, but until then, use C++.

Comment: It does not have to compile down to native code. It can compile to bytecode and run in a VM.

Comment: As for SWT, I have used Vuze and eclipse, on Linux they look awful. I did set up the GTK theme. On several themes I have used there are several visual quirks. Also all the Java apps I have used have extremely high RAM usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for libgc! It seems to provide what I was looking for.

Comment: Eclipse looks awful? Then you have some extremely high standards. What application does not look awful to you then? :)

Comment: Well at least on some GTK themes the tooltips have unreadable text. http://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity
There are also many other graphical glitches.
Most of these problems are on Linux though, eclipse looks fine on windows.
It looks way better then swing, but you can spot SWT right away.
I think Qt does a really good job on all platforms. Much better then SWT.
Edit: I think for many cases SWT may be "good enough" but Java still suffers from very high RAM use.
A garbage collected C++ with Qt will be perfect though!

Answer (score 2):

What about [`vala`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_%28programming_language%29)?

> Vala is an object-oriented programming language with a self-hosting
>   compiler that generates C code and uses the GObject system. Vala is
>   syntactically similar to C# and includes useful language features like
>   anonymous functions, signals, properties, generics, assisted memory
>   management, exception handling, type inference, and foreach
>   statements.[2](http://golang.org/) It is being developed by Jürg Billeter and Raffaele
>   Sandrini. It aims to bring modern language features to C[clarification
>   needed][peacock term], with no added runtime needs and with little
>   overhead, by targeting the GObject object system. Rather than being
>   compiled directly to assembly or to another intermediate language,
>   Vala is source-to-source compiled to C which is then compiled with a
>   platform's standard C compiler, such as gcc.

[`Go`](http://golang.org/) there is as well some bindings for GTK,  FLTK and WALK. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781341/which-gui-toolkit-for-go-language) thread.

Comment: +2 for two good answers!

Comment: I tried some Vala and for all practical purposes it is Linux only.
There is no OSX version and there hasn't been a Windows binary release in 18months. I'm not sure if the sources compile on windows and the binary release was also borked the last time I tried to use it. Also AFAIK gtk3 still hasn't been ported to windows yet.

Comment: @n3wu53r you might want to take a look at http://www.tarnyko.net/dl/

Answer (score 1):

On Java you can still modify the Look and Feel of your UI. Java gets also a port of Qt called [Qt Jambi](http://qt-jambi.org/).

Answer (score 1):

And then there are very stable languages like Free Pascal/Lazarus and PureBasic that work well (same source code compiles on all platforms) on Win, OS X and Linux

Comment: FPC/Lazarus is not garbage collected. IMHO thank god though.

Answer (score 0):

[Real Studio](http://www.realsoftware.com) uses reference counting for automated memory management.  It's not garbage collection, but better in many ways.

And of course Real Studio runs on Windows, OS X and Linux and can create apps for Windows, OS X, Linux and the web.

Comment: One problem with Real Studio:
http://www.realsoftware.com/realstudio/fulllicense
The largest paragraph on the page after the bullets.

Not that It may even affect me but that part of the license seems very draconian.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Qt Quick. It has a declarative UI language called QML and it's scriptable with javascript.